# ¿Cómo puedo validar que una fecha sea mayor, meno o igual a otra con javascript-php?

Tags: javascript, date

He intentado comparar 2 fechas que se ingresan desde 2 inputs, estas fechas son seleccionadas mediante el datepicker con el calendario que proporciona materialize. Pero al realizar la comparación para que el código compare las fecha este nada mas valida los días pero no los meses ni los años.

El código que usaba es el siguiente:

```js
<script>
function ValidarFechas()
{
var fechainicial = document.getElementById("FechaInicial").value;
var fechafinal = document.getElementById("FechaFinal").value;

if(fechafinal < fechainicial)

alert("La fecha final debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");

}
```

Pero como ya mencioné esta función únicamente valida el día sin considerar el mes ni el año.

Comment: Intentó usar `Date.parse(fechainicial) ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que recibió una fecha en formato de Fecha de Javascript, puede usar la función [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/parse) o comparar por operadores de comparación.

Algo como esto::

```
if(Date.parse(fechafinal) < Date.parse(fechainicial)){
   //La fecha final es menor que la inicial
}else{
   //La fecha Final es mayor...
}
```

Entonces su código quedaría asi:

```js
<script>
function ValidarFechas()
{
   var fechainicial = document.getElementById("FechaInicial").value;
   var fechafinal = document.getElementById("FechaFinal").value;

   if(Date.parse(fechafinal) < Date.parse(fechainicial)) {

   alert("La fecha final debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");
}
</script>
```

Comment: cual seria el formato de la fecha javascript amigo?

Comment: Si lo prueba de esta manera le funciona correctamente: `var fechainicial = new Date(2018,05,14);
var fechafinal = new Date(2018,05,13);` Aquí esta recibiendo `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Cual es el formato actual que usted esta usando?

Comment: amigo me funcionó a la perfección, te lo agradezco. Solo una consulta, tuve que cambiar el formato al que me dijiste para que funcionara. Hay alguna manera de que funcione igual si el formato es dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: estaba trabajando con dd/mm/yyyy. Tuve que cambiarlo al formato de javascript para que funcionara.

Comment: No sé si es tarde. Pero de igual forma válidas en PHP generalmente esos son los campos donde más usan los sql inyection

Comment: @Rodriguez1222 supongo que si, vea esto: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @JackNavaRow solo traté de resolver el problema con el poco conocimiento que tengo, pero en cuestion de seguridad pues aqui en esta pregunta de SO: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/69447) hay mucha información al respecto para evitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas las libreria [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) solo necesitarás una función como esta:
(El ejemplo esta en JQuery, pero en javascript es muy similar)

```
function comprobarMayoria(dateSelected){                   
    var fechanacimiento = moment(dateSelected, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var years = moment().diff(fechanacimiento, 'years');
    return years >= 18 ? true : false
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script>
    function ValidarFechas()
    {
    var fechainicial = document.getElementById("FechaInicial").value;
    var fechafinal = document.getElementById("FechaFinal").value;

    if(fechafinal.year > fechainicial.year || fechafinal.month > fechainicial.month || fechafinal.day > fechainicial.day)

    alert("La fecha final debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial");

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: no solo debes colocar código, sino explicarlo; además dale formato sleccionandolo y da clic en el ícono de `{}`